# I/O Voltage of JFET Common Source with source degeneration

Tags: mosfet, output, jfet, formula-derivation

For common source JFET (n-channel):  Uin = Ugs (approximation for simplicity), but really Uin is a little bit lower because of input resistance, like so and Uout equals something like this:

[image]

But how is it for common sorce JFET with source degeneration? How does the equation for each Uin & Uout looks like? I know that Rs lowers the voltage gain so there must be any changes here, right?

[image]

- As for the Au (voltage gain) concerns for I know the how formula looks like. It applies Rs to equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression for \$V_o\$ value is the same. 
$$V_o = -g_mV_{gs}R_D$$

But with \$R_S\$ resistor added into the circuit \$V_{in}\$ is no longer equal to \$V{gs}\$.

Because now \$V_{gs} = V_{in} - V_s = V_{in} -I_DR_S=V_{in} -g_mV_{gs}R_S  \$

Now we can find \$V_{in}\$ voltage

$$V_{in} = V_{gs}+I_DR_S = V_{gs} + g_mV_{gs}R_S = V_{gs}\left (1+g_mR_S  \right )  $$

Hence the voltage gain is equal to: 
$$\frac{V_o}{V_{in}}= \frac{-g_mV_{gs}R_D}{V_{gs}\left (1+g_mR_S  \right )}= - \frac{g_mR_D}{1+g_mR_S} = - \frac{R_D}{\frac{1}{g_m} + R_S}$$

Side note: 
**JFET** is a junction field-effect transistor.

And the circuit diagram symbol for any **JFET** look like this:

[image]

And for the enhancement **MOSFET** (Metal-Oxide Semiconductor Field-Effect Transistor) transistors look like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow that was amazing!

Comment: Do all this equations (equations for CS, CD & CG) apply for MOSFETs configurations? As the thing concerns of Rin, Rout, Au, Uin & Uout?

Comment: @Keno The equations for ( Rin, Rout, Au, Uin & Uout) look exactly the same for the MOSFET's and JFET's.

Comment: Also the Av gain for CE amplifier is \$A_V= - g_mR_C\$ or we can write it this way\$A_V = -\frac{Rc}{\frac{1}{gm}}\$  and with \$R_E\$ resistor \$Av = - \frac{R_C}{\frac{1}{gm}+R_E} \$ looks familiar ?